# "Can't Assign to Literal" in python

Tags: python

I am coding a quiz in python 3.5.1 and on one of my questions it says "can't assign to literal". I am trying to ask if someone is a boy or girl and then have the variable 'gender' be either "Yes" or "No" depending on what they say. But if they do not say "Yes" or "No" then it says "I Do Not Know What (and then what they said) Means". But then it says "can't assign to literal" and highlights the first "=" in line 9. Here is the code.

```
q2 = 0
while q2 == 0:
    q2 = input ("Are You a Boy or a Girl?")
if q2 == ("Boy"):
    gender = ("Boy")
if q2 == ("Girl"):
    gender = ("Girl")
else:
    qbq = "I Do Not Know What " = repr(q2) + " Means"
    print (qbq)
```

Comment: Well, what do you expect `"I Do Not Know What " = repr(q2)` to do?

Comment: You have a typo: the `=` after `"I Do Not Know What "` should be a `+`

Comment: Thx did not see that

Answer (score 1):

Change `=` to `+` before `repr` perhaps?

Comment: Thx I did not see that